# Android NPE TypeFace

Tags: android, button, fonts, assets

I set a font from the assets folder for each present the Activity button, I do not understand why I get a NPE at line 56 which is this:`pswET.setTypeface(tf);`where am I wrong?

04-25 18:18:49.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1853): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    enter code here
    -25 18:18:49.983: E/AndroidRuntime(1853):   at main.Login.onCreate(Login.java:56)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPrefName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    boolean value;  
    String name = getPackageName() + "_PREFERENCES";
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(name, MODE_PRIVATE);
    //control if there is no password
    if (!sp.contains(Util.PREF_PSW) || "".equals(sp.getString(Util.PREF_PSW, null))) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        //check if the key is stored yes / no for the password
    } if (value = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("check", true)) {
        setContentView(R.layout.tastiera_password);
    }else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"roboto.ttf");
    pswET = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.psw);
    pswET.setTypeface(tf);
    bb1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    bb1.setTypeface(tf);
    bb2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
    bb2.setTypeface(tf);
    bb3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
    bb3.setTypeface(tf);
    bb4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
    bb4.setTypeface(tf);
    bb5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b5);
    bb5.setTypeface(tf);
    bb6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b6);
    bb6.setTypeface(tf);
    bb7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b7);
    bb7.setTypeface(tf);
    bb8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b8);
    bb8.setTypeface(tf);
    bb9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b9);
    bb9.setTypeface(tf);
    bb0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b0);
    bb0.setTypeface(tf);
      // Set the listener for all the buttons
    int numberButtons[] = { R.id.b1, R.id.b2, R.id.b3,
      R.id.b4, R.id.b5, R.id.b6, R.id.b7,
      R.id.b8, R.id.b9, R.id.b0
    };
    NumberButtonClickListener numberClickListener = new NumberButtonClickListener();
    for(int id : numberButtons) {
     View v = findViewById(id);
     v.setOnClickListener(numberClickListener);
    }
    }
private class NumberButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)  {
        String text = (String) ((Button)v).getText();           

            setCurrentString(getCurrentString()+text);

    }
     public void setCurrentString(String s) {
            currentString = s;
            pswET.setText(s);
        }
        public String getCurrentString() {
            return currentString;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findViewById failed, either because you didn't set the content view or because you use an id that doesn't exist.  Remember that finish() does not end execution of the function-  to do that you need to return, so if you go into that branch of your if/else you'll never have sent a content view and findViewById will always return null.